# save data for all tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, tabs, updates

I have made a profile page of a tab bar of length 3. and I have a save icon in the app bar.  the 3 pages (tabs) views are in different files.
is there any way by which I can save the data of all 3 tabs just by clicking the save button on the main profile page?
Below is the screenshot of the page.
[image]

so is there a way by which I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

An idea i think is simple,save the data to sharedpreference,then get it once you press the save button.